# How to reverse first name and last name globally

Tags: customer, localisation, customer-attribute

Can someone please tell me how can change customer name format globally?

I want to show customer name as Last name First name instead of First name then Last name.

I ask this because I'm doing an e-commerce site in Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

in magento `full name` are comming from `addNameToSelect()` function of class `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection` and getName() function of class `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`.You need change there by rewrite classes.

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento70422>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento70422_Model</class>
      </magento70422>
            <customer_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_collection>Stackexchange_Magento70422_Model_Customer_Resource_Customer_Collection</customer_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </customer_resource>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>Stackexchange_Magento70422_Model_Customer_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
    </models>
  </global>
```

**Rewrite class  of Mage_Customer_Model_Customer**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento70422_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{

   public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        //$name .= $this->getFirstname();
    $name .=  $this->getLastname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        //$name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
    $name .= ' ' . $this->getFirstname();   
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Rewrite resource collection  class of `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection` is below:

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento70422_Model_Customer_Resource_Customer_Collection extends Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
{
public function addNameToSelect()
    {
        $fields = array();
        $customerAccount = Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account');
        foreach ($customerAccount as $code => $node) {
            if ($node->is('name')) {
                $fields[$code] = $code;
            }
        }

        $adapter = $this->getConnection();
        $concatenate = array();
        if (isset($fields['prefix'])) {
            $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
                '{{prefix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{prefix}} != \'\'',
                $adapter->getConcatSql(array('LTRIM(RTRIM({{prefix}}))', '\' \'')),
                '\'\'');
        }
       // $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}}))';
        $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';

        $concatenate[] = '\' \'';
        if (isset($fields['middlename'])) {
            $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
                '{{middlename}} IS NOT NULL AND {{middlename}} != \'\'',
                $adapter->getConcatSql(array('LTRIM(RTRIM({{middlename}}))', '\' \'')),
                '\'\'');
        }
       // $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}}))'
        if (isset($fields['suffix'])) {
            $concatenate[] = $adapter
                    ->getCheckSql('{{suffix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{suffix}} != \'\'',
                $adapter->getConcatSql(array('\' \'', 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{suffix}}))')),
                '\'\'');
        }

        $nameExpr = $adapter->getConcatSql($concatenate);

        $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name', $nameExpr, $fields);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The "Bill to Name" field in Sales -> Orders table is still in the original format (First name then Last name). I'm wondering why magento get customer name functions are placed in so many places.

Comment: you need to change all position

Comment: god bless me... Anyway, thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0):

In `\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php` there is a method called `getName()` that looks like this:

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

Change it by simply inversing `getFirstname` with `getLastname`.
To change this without modifying the core file, you can copy this file to the `local` code pool, or create your own module and rewrite this method in it.

Comment: Isn't this better handled by Mage_Directory? Or is name formatting not in there? Been a while since I looked at it.